# Drupal Views: Render Null Result for Relationship as 0

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have a View configured in Drupal to return nodes, sorting them by their average vote in descending order. For the purpose of the View, the value of the average votes is a Relationship. I noticed that nodes with no votes are displayed after nodes with a negative average. Nodes with no votes should have an average of 0, but I believe the MySQL `JOIN` is causing `NULL` values to be returned (as there are no matching rows in the joined table, since a row is created after the first vote is cast for that item).

I discovered that with MySQL it is possible to output all values that are `NULL` in a column as another value with `IFNULL(column_name,'other value')`.

I feel like I would need to modify the Views module in order to obtain this functionality, but I'm hoping that there is some sort of option that returns `NULL` values in a relation (a relation doesn't exist for the item) as 0 instead of `NULL`, so that I can properly sort the nodes.

The modules I am using include Views, Voting API, Vote Up/Down, and CTools.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oooh, please don't modify Views directly.

Just write a plugin. It's all object-oriented, so you just write a field handler that extends the exiting handler for that field. `hook_views_handlers` is the place to start for that.

All you'll need to do is copy-paste the existing handler, make your tweaks to the SQL, and give the field a new name. It'll show up in your list of available fields like any other.

-- Edit --

Views documentation can be a little confusing at first if you've never done it before, but it's super-simple once you get that "ahah!" moment.

A good place to start would be looking at other modules that extend views, and copying their tricks. The docs at http://views2.logrus.com/doc/html/index.html will help you get a sense of how the objects are mapped.

Personally, I would make the modification in the `->render()` method instead of in the `->query()` method. That way you can just add a simple `if (is_null($value)) {$value = 0;}` instead of using SQL tricks.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't necessarily planning on modifying Views itself, but I thought that is where I would need to go to modify the functionality that it provides, as opposed to altering the Voting modules. Extending the functionality through a plugin seems like it would work as you said.

Comment: I edited my response with some links and recommendations -- good luck!